# Every other request is routed differently

Tags: laravel, nginx, dns, ipv6

In my php MVC framework (laravel on apache), every other request is failing to route properly. My php instance is behind an nginx server.

What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx was forwarding to `localhost`, and `localhost` is defined in `/etc/hosts` as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

...so every other request was routing as ipv6, and the ipv6 path through laravel was buggy.

**moral**: alternating breakage may relate to ipv6 & localhost.

Comment: or multiple "host record" resolutions, as it can happen with DNS as well